# Is there a way to record video with the Windows Game Bar and add to it a camera at the same time?

Tags: camera, recording, windows-8-games

What title says.
I'm using to record my gameplays Windows Game Bar (pressing WIN + G to open it) but I'm facing with the problem of that doesn't allow to record your face with your Web Camera.

There is a way to do that?

Comment: Windows Game Bar does not have the functionality you want.  You will have to look to third-party software.

Comment: If you are not streaming, you can use editing software to add the camera lateron. You just need to record the camera seperately to a different movie.

Comment: Ok, that was I was thinking about.. Thanks! :D

Comment: You may want to have a look at [OBS](https://obsproject.com) if you have a decent PC.